# Need solution to "The app returned "The columnid xxxxxxx is invalid"" when using Zapier New Row Update for Smartsheet

Tags: zapier, smartsheet-api

I'm looking for a solution to a problem that's occurring when using Zapier to update cells in one smartsheet from cells in another smartsheet.

When using the Zapier New Row Update action on a Smartsheet, it's throwing an error:  "The app returned "The columnId xxxxxxxx is invalid".  This is occurring when trying to update one cell in each of two different rows in a destination smartsheet where we have just completed a Copy Row action from a source smartsheet using Zapier.  Additionally, Zapier also reports while stepping through the errored action that there are unused columns in the Zap and once removed, the update will complete and is repeatable on the same sheet.  However, it fails the next time an update is attempted on a new destination smartsheet.  If you've had this problem before and resolved it, please respond.

Answer (score 0):

Zapier will only grab data from a row/column that has a data in it.

I've only had this error when Airtable was attempting to send a record within a row that had an empty column.

For me, a "House Number" was missing from this specific row, (other ones were OK). Smartsheet is unable to grab {nothing} as a value it seems.

| Street | House Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1st Ave | 01 |
| 2nd Ave |  |

If able, populate your field with NULL/0 or even a delimiter -- that way post-flow you can merely setup another workflow which delimits the rows in question.

| Street | House Number |
| --- | --- |
| 1st Ave | 01 |
| 2nd Ave | NULL |
| 3rd Ave | , |

Sorry if this answer was spastic,